# how to make a javascript news vertical ticker?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have a vertical news feed ticker where each element is displayed for few seconds then replaced with the next one using only javascript (since jQuery seems to be causing problems with other libraries used in the page I am working on).

Any suggestions of JS libraries to use?

Comment: This is a generalised question that really needs research. There are countless plugins and tutorials on this sort of thing. If you need help with something SPECIFIC, post some code, and we can help with that.

Comment: @Sam I'm not sure I understand. You said "using only Javascript, since jQuery is causing problems", implying that you dont want to use other js libraries (jQuery is just a js library), but then you ask for other js libraries

Comment: @Sam also, don't throw away jquery because you found some issues with it. jQuery is an invaluable tool. I would suggest re-importing jQuery and trying $.noConflict() on doc ready to see if you can get rid of some of the conflicts

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt sorry for the confusion .. I need pure javascript code to do this.

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt I am trying using $ noConflict()

Comment: @Sam actually try jQuery.noConflict() as it is possible that another function has already taken over the $ variable

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt yup it worked, thanks a million :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize jQuery.noConflict() if it collides with other libraries.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/